# Undefined property: stdClass::$title

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i want to fetch the record from database which pages without parent_id or we can say pages without parent..

the page model
..........................................

```
public function get_no_parents() {
// fecth pages wihtout parents
$this->db->select ( 'id','title' );
$this->db->where ( 'parent_id', 0 );
$pages = parent::get ();
// if there are pages then return key as page->id and value $page->title
$array = array (
0 => 'no parent'
);

if(is_array($pages)){

foreach ($pages as $page){

 $array[$page->id]=$page->title;
   $return $array;


    }
  }
}
```

.....the page controller

```
$this->data['pages_no_parents']=$this->Page_model->get_no_parents();
    var_dump($this->data['pages_no_parents']);
```

....
the dump is null i have two error

1- Undefined property: stdClass::$title

2- Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

can someone help me ?

Comment: still the problem exists

Comment: still *a* problem exists, but you have another one. What does `parent::get();` returns ?

Comment: it will return the pages from the database from the parent class

Comment: Well, it should, but it does not returns an array... `var_dump` it

Comment: no one error is fixed , Undefined property: stdClass::$title still i am getting error

Comment: array
  0 => string 'no parent' (length=9)
  1 => null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
$this->db->select ( 'id','title' );
```

To:

```
$this->db->select ( 'id, title' );
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thnks it worked , can you explain it to me  ? what is the differece between them ?

Comment: `$this->db->select()` only takes 2 params: 1) the select string 2) a flag to show if the string should be escaped. So, when you have `('id', 'title')` `id` was the only string that was getting passed as part of the select if that makes sense?